# java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host

Tags: java

After a hard work, I have set up Java RMI tunnelling using apache as http 
server. Everything is fine and Works like a charm at my office LAN.But when I installed at client's place, I am getting some exception.The RMI System works only on his server.

When I tried from other clients' pcs I get the following.

Can you guys help me solve this?

```
 java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 172.xx.x.xxx;
 nested exception is:   java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed
 out: connect   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown
 Source)    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown
 Source)    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown
 Source)    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
 java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(Unknown
 Source)    at
 java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at $Proxy1.getUserID(Unknown Source)    at
 rmi.source.ServerImpl$JobScheduler.run(ServerImpl.java:265)    at
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)     at
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect   at
 java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)  at
 java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)     at
 java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)  at
 java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)   at
 java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)   at
 java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)    at
 java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)    at
 java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)     at
 java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)     at
 sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown
 Source)    at
 sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown
 Source)    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 2):

I am running files from roseindia rmi
there is mistake rmicregistry, one have to use `rmiregistry`:

I changed ip to localhost, how to run on special port number I don't know this moment
one has to use rmiregistry
not rmicregistry

so: 
move to folder where does your class files take seat.
type : `rmiregistry`
then open 2 new command prompts move to same folder where classes seat and use one to run server and another to client.

Answer (score 1):

RMI servers have the nasty habit to pass new port numbers to clients to handle the client communication to a particular Remote object. If this port number is blocked by the firewall, you would get an exception like that. 
Make sure you register all Remote objects with the same port number. RMI will then multiplex the client calls for you.

Comment: I use LocateRegistry.getRegistry(rmiHost, rmiPort,new sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIHttpToCGISocketFactory()) to get registry by passing same port
I am creating a single remote object in the server to be used by all applet clients.

Also I have given full permissions in java.policy file in jre and catalina.policy file as well.
Interestingly there is no fire-wall m/c inbetween to route requests to server.
But windows fire-wall enabled on each m/c.This is the same set up at my office where RMI System works fine.

Comment: how do you create the server-side remote objects? Do they inherit from UnicastRemoteObject and if so, which super.ctor are you using?

Comment: Thank you for reply I was on leave.My server class inherits UnicastRemoteObject. The constructor I use is just super()

Comment: Thanks.But passing port to super(port) throws exception [[Caused by: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1531; nested exception is:]] Because port is passed to registry before

Answer (score 0):

after my research, the solution is:
`System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", IP)`; 
before you register the service on server side. following is an example, hope it might help you!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, RemoteException, AlreadyBoundException {
        RmiServer server=new RmiServer();
        System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", 指定IP);
        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(8808);  
        Naming.rebind("//10.10.116.74:8808/SAMPLE-SERVER", server);  
    }
```